# Present a ViewController that is embedded in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a situation wherein a storyboard made VC(embedded in NavController) should be presented programmatically.

SomeVC -> presents NavController(rootVC) -> rootVC -> pushes subVC

on this representation, subVC should have a back button to go back to rootVC, but I can't implement it this way. Will be providing sample codes that I have already tried.

this pushes the rootVC directly:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoard" bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootVC"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

also tried pushing the navigationController itself, ID has been set on storyboard:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: storyboard implementation]

EDIT: storyboard implementation looks like this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to present a navigation controller and have those rootVC and subVC already in it, right? So after presenting, you want the subVC to be presented with the back button right away.

If that's the case you need to tell the navigation controller to push the subVC before presenting it

```
UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
UIViewController *subVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"subVC"];
[navController pushViewController:subVC animated:NO];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, for starters, I just want to show rootVC and when the user taps on certain button, it will push the subVC. the problem right now is when i present the navController, the subVC is not having the back button of navigatoin

Comment: subVC is called using the segue made from storyboard. on Storyboard, rootVC is already embedded on navigationController.

Comment: Interesting. Do the subVC’s naivagation item have a left bar button item?

Comment: The default back button on storyboard, yes.

Comment: Can I see your codes where you present the navVC and the subVC?

Comment: Hi, I tried presenting the navController using the codes posted on the question, while the presentation of subVC is just a push segue on the storyboard.

Comment: The only explanation for this case is that there is a bar button item set for the `leftBarButtonItem` on the subVC's navigation item. Could you try to check that?

Comment: On storyboard, there is a back button on subVC, since it is pushed from a navigation controller. there is no `leftBarButtonItem` on the view controllers object hierarchy. I hope my sentence makes sense.

Comment: May I have a look at your storyboard? Also could you try to debug the view controller hierarchy at runtime with the UI Debugger?

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of storyboard implementation. (NOTE: button should be "Push Sub VC")

Comment: I think you may need to debug it at runtime and see if there's a left button item set there at runtime. Everything you showed me looks normal to me. One case that I can think of now is that you change the left bar button item at runtime